# Coincidence matrix from array with clusters assignments

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array containing the cluster assigned to every point.

```
import numpy as np
cluster_labels = np.array([1,1,2,3,4])
```

How can I get a matrix like:

```
1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1
```

I'm sure there is something clever than:

```
import numpy as np

cluster_labels = np.array([1,1,2,3,4])
n = cluster_labels.shape[0]
pairwise_clustering = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n):
        if cluster_labels[i] == cluster_labels[j]:
            pairwise_clustering[i,j] = 1

print pairwise_clustering


[[ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

**Edit** (bonus):
I'm interested in the mean pairwise clustering of a set of $n$ `cluster_labels`. So I would like to get the mean of the pairwise_clustering directly from an array of many `cluster_labels`:

```
n_cluster_labels = np.array([[1,1,2,3,4],
                             [1,2,3,3,4],
                             [1,1,2,3,4]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say whether what your doing is the best way to tackle the problem without knowing more about the problem itself.

However, it is possible to get the matrix your looking for in far less code:

```
x = np.array([1,1,2,3,4])
(x[None,:] == x[:,None]).astype(int)
```

Conceptually it does the same as your code. It just uses some more of numpy's features instead of python for-loops.

Indexing `x` as `x[None,:]` adds a dummy axis of length 1. We then exploit numpy's broadcasting feature and apply the equal operator element-wise on the broadcasted arrays. In the end we convert the boolean result to integers. (replace `int` with `float` to get floating point numbers instead).

Comment: Thanks Leeming! What kind of extra information do you need? I have just $N$ clustering proposals (with a label for every point) and I would like to get these pairwise matrices. Actually I will take the average of the pairwise matrices.

Comment: @alberto I'm most likely not an expert in your field. E.g. I'm not sure what cluster really means in this context. So, reading your question made me think of the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). That first line was just meant as a disclaimer that I'm assuming that you really need these matrices in that shape from that input. If that's the case, then there is nothing to worry about.