# Fastest coincidence matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays and I want to compute a list/array of coincidences. That is, a list of all the indices i, j so that a[i] == b[j]. This is my code now:

```
b = np.array([3, 5, 6, 4])
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

np.array([[i, j] for i in range(a.size) for j in range(b.size) if a[i] == b[j]])
```

Is there a faster (maybe numpy-powered) way to do this?

Comment: How big are the input arrays in your actual use case?

Comment: Also, would there be duplicates within each of the arrays?

Comment: @Divakar 10e5 approx, and there may be duplicated values in the arrays

Answer (score 2):

#### Approach #1

One approach would be using `np.in1d` -

```
m_a = np.in1d(a,b)
I = np.flatnonzero(m_a)
J = np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(b, a[m_a]))
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [367]: a
Out[367]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [368]: b
Out[368]: array([3, 5, 6, 4])

In [370]: I
Out[370]: array([2, 3])

In [371]: J
Out[371]: array([0, 3])
```

#### Approach #2

Another straight-forward but memory heavy way would be with `broadcasting` -

```
I,J = np.nonzero(a[:,None] == b)
```

#### Approach #3

For the case where we have no duplicates within the input arrays, we could use `np.searchsorted`. There are two variants here - One for sorted `a`, and another for a generic `a`.

**Variant #1 :** For sorted `a` -

```
idx = np.searchsorted(a, b)
idx[idx==a.size] = 0
mask = a[idx] == b
I = np.searchsorted(a,b[mask])
J = np.flatnonzero(mask)
```

**Variant #2 :** For this generic variant case, we need to use argsort indices of `a` -

```
sidx = a.argsort()
a_sort = a[sidx]
idx = np.searchsorted(a_sort, b)
idx[idx==a.size] = 0
mask = a_sort[idx] == b
I = sidx[np.searchsorted(a_sort,b[mask])]
J = np.flatnonzero(mask)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `numpy` solution might be using the function [numpy.argwhere()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy.argwhere), which can be used to find indices of an array that conform with a given condition.

```
ax = np.tensordot(a, np.ones(len(a)), axes = 0)
bx = np.tensordot(np.ones(len(b)), b, axes = 0)
np.argwhere(ax - bx == 0)
```

The indices of zero elements of `ax - bx` are just those that correspond to equal elements of `a` and `b`, because there the constant rows rsp. columns of the tensor products 'intersect'. Not sure, whether this solution is faster, though.

Comment: This answer compares the elements point-to-point the array. I need is to compare all elements from a with all elements from b

Comment: Sorry, got that wrong. Edited for reflecting your comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Already solved, but here's the timing]:

I have compared your solution to a more python-list way, as well as the proposed matrix solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028213/coincidence-matrix-from-array-with-clusters-assignments): (you would need to get the indexes from that matrix though).

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

random.seed(12345)
b = [random.randint(0,100000) for i in range(10000)]
a = [random.randint(0,100000) for i in range(10000)]
```

In order to get a more accurate timing (for large datasets) I have created two lists of (pseudo)random integers that are 1e5 values long.

```
#List based approach
start_time = time.time()
c2 = [[i,j]  for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(b)) if a[i] == b[j]]
print time.time() - start_time # t = 29.2776758671

b = np.array(a)
a = np.array(b)

#NumPy Array based approach    
start_time = time.time()
c1 = np.array([[i, j] for i in range(a.size) for j in range(b.size) if a[i] == b[j]])
print time.time() - start_time # t = 46.374776125
```

Not a huge time difference, there, although it takes slightly shorter without using numpy arrays, it still means quite long computation times for large vectors.

Creating an intermediary solution in the shape of a coincidence

```
#Coincidence Matrix (NumPy) based approach    
start_time = time.time()
c3 = (a[None,:] == b[:,None]).astype(int)
c3s = np.where(c3 == 1)
print time.time() - start_time # t = 0.857568979263
```

I have also timed another solution that was posted before, and seems to be the fastest way to solve this:

```
c4 = np.nonzero(a[:,None] == b)
# t = 0.399062156677
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** algo handles duplicates now. Code is quite complicated, unfortunately. But fast, see rough benchmarks at the end of this post.

If your arrays are nonneg int, and you have enough memory, then the following is a bit faster than what was posted before. Benchmarking code mostly borrowed from @Dominique Fuchs

```
import numpy as np
import random
import itertools as it
import time

random.seed(12345)
b = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (10000,))
a = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (10000,))
#a = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10000,)))
#b = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(0, 20, (10000,)))
np.random.shuffle(a)
np.random.shuffle(b)


#Coincidence Matrix (NumPy) based approach (dominique fuchs)
start_time = time.time()
c3 = (a[None,:] == b[:,None]).astype(int)
c3s = np.where(c3 == 1)
t = time.time() - start_time
print('df      {: 12.6f}'.format(1000*t))


# divakar approach 1
start_time = time.time()
m_a = np.in1d(a,b)
I = np.flatnonzero(m_a)
J = np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(b, a[m_a]))
t = time.time() - start_time
print('div 1   {: 12.6f}'.format(1000*t))

# divakar approach 2
start_time = time.time()
I,J = np.nonzero(a[:,None] == b)
t = time.time() - start_time
print('div 2   {: 12.6f}'.format(1000*t))


# bm
import collections

def default(a):
    d=collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in enumerate(a):
        d[v].append(k)
    return d

def coincidences(a,b):
    aa=default(a)
    bb=default(b)
    ab=set(aa.keys()) & set(bb.keys())
    l=[]
    for k in ab:
      for i in aa[k]:
          for j in bb[k]:
              l.append((i,j))
    return l


start_time = time.time()
l = coincidences(a, b)
t = time.time() - start_time
print('bm      {: 12.6f}'.format(1000*t))


# my (pp) approach
start_time = time.time()
ws = np.empty((100000,), dtype=int)
ws[b] = -1
ws[a] = np.arange(len(a))
b_ind = np.flatnonzero(ws[b] > -1)
a_ind = ws[b[b_ind]]
# find duplicates
wsa = ws[a]
# writing to ws[a] above duplicate values in a mean that the same memory
# is written multiple times and only the value written with the last
# occurrence of the duplicate survives.
# All other occurrences can therefore be found by
dup = np.flatnonzero(wsa != np.arange(len(a)))
# Next we have to separate groups of duplicates which at this point are
# all jumbled together.
# This is done by argsorting and grouping keyed by the index of the
# last occurrence.
didx = np.argsort(wsa[dup])
dups = dup[didx]
wsad = wsa[dups]
# Find indices where the key changes, in other words group boundaries.
# Append one bin for junk. (Things marked with index -1 will find their 
# way there.)
split = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, wsad[:-1] != wsad[1:], True, True])
split[-1] -= 1
# split duplicate indices into groups.
blocks = np.split(dups, split[1:-2])
ws[a] = -1
ws[a[dups[split[:-2]]]] = np.arange(len(split)-2)
# For each match in b grps will hold the index of the group of
# corresponding duplicates in a; non-matches are marked -1
grps = ws[b[b_ind]]
# Whereever the last occurrence of a duplicate in a was matched to an
# element of b, the corresponding group also matches.
# The index of the element of b must be repeated to keep b_ind and      
# a_ind (where the group will be inserted) in sync
b_ind = np.repeat(b_ind, 1 + np.diff(split)[grps])
# cut up a wherever the last occurrence of a group of duplicates is found
split = np.flatnonzero(grps > -1)
a_chunks = np.split(a_ind, split)
# insert the corresponding groups and rejoin
a_ind = np.concatenate([c for a in it.zip_longest(a_chunks, (blocks[g] for g in grps[split]), fillvalue=np.array([], int)) for c in a])
t = time.time() - start_time
print('pp      {: 12.6f}'.format(1000*t))


o1 = np.lexsort(c3s)
o2 = np.lexsort((b_ind, a_ind))

print(np.all(c3s[1][o1] == a_ind[o2]) and np.all(c3s[0][o1] == b_ind[o2]))
```

Sample Output:

```
#df        652.901411
#div 1       3.543615
#div 2     332.098961
#bm         14.440775
#pp          1.211882     <----- my solution
#True
```

Answer (score 1):

A (very) fast solution based on dicts sets and lists, which is linear in time and space, whatever the data, duplicates or not, big keys or not.

```
a,b = np.random.randint(0,10**8,size=(2,10**4))

import collections

def default(a):
    d=collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in enumerate(a):
        d[v].append(k)
    return d

def coincidences(a,b):
    aa=default(a)
    bb=default(b)
    ab=set(aa.keys()) & set(bb.keys())
    l=[]
    for k in ab:
      for i in aa[k]:
          for j in bb[k]:
              l.append((i,j))
    return l
```

Runs:

```
In [125]: %timeit coincidences(a,b)
10.6 ms ± 402 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Numpy only wins when it can implement a linear solution.

**EDIT**

The equivalent Pandas solution (same timings) :

```
def coincidences_pd(a,b):        
    aa=pd.DataFrame(list(range(len(a))),a)
    bb=pd.DataFrame(list(range(len(b))),b)
    return pd.merge(aa,bb,left_index=True,right_index=True)

In [219]: coincidences_pd(a,b)
Out[219]: 
           0_x   0_y
54025822  1752  8046
84735197  7301  2956
```

Comment: _"... linear in time and space, whatever the data."_ Are you sure of that? I'm not an expert but I seem to remember that hash tables have terrible worst case.

Comment: yes, amortized. quadratic complexity can happen (like for quicksort) but it  statistically  never arise.